# Excel VBA: Creating a new sheet off of a variable name and then formatting it from a master copy

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Im attempting a bit of code that creates a sheet with a name set by a variable, and then formatting this new sheet by copy/pasting all the cells from a master to this new sheet. The issue I'm having is referring to this new sheet once it's created as the title is stored in a variable.

Currently, my code is as below, everything works except for the last line where I'm attempting to select the newly created worksheet by referring to it by the variable name.

```
Sub Create_New_Sheet()

    Dim title As String
    
    title = Sheets("config").range("A3 ").Value & "_" & Sheets("config").range("B3 ").Value & "_" & "Calculations"

    Sheets.Add(Before:=Sheets("Results")).Name = title

    Sheets("Calc_master").UsedRange.Copy
    Sheets("title").range("A1").Paste

End Sub
```

Is there a way to select the sheet using the variable? I haven't been able to find anything to suggest it can.

Comment: `Sheets(title).range("A1").Paste`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding or copying a worksheet the new worksheet will be the activesheet.

But consider *copying* the calc_master-sheet - no need to copy/paste the usedrange:

```vb
Function get_New_Sheet() as Worksheet

    Dim title As String
    Dim wsConfig As Worksheet, wsMaster as Worksheet
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set wsConfig = .Worksheets("Config")
        With wsConfig
            title = .Range("A3") & "_" & .Range("B3") & "_Calculations"
        End With
           
        Set wsMaster = .Worksheets("Calc_master")
        wsMaster.Copy before:=.Worksheets("Results")
    End With
    
    ActiveSheet.Name = title
    Set get_New_Sheet = ActiveSheet
End Function
```

Within your larger scope:

```vb
Public Sub doSomething

Dim wsNew as worksheet
Set wsNew = get_New_Sheet

wsNew.Range("A1") = "xxx"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I hadn't considered copying the sheet and then renaming it. This code is part of a larger project, now that the sheet is created, what would be the best way to refer to it in the code?

Comment: I changed the sub to a function - the function returns the new sheet - see the last code part - it shows you how to use it. You can even enhance it, e.g. by passing the row to `get_New_sheet`